# Firebase Storage Link doesn't Render Thumbnail in Facebook or Twitter

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase storage within an iOS app to store video and images. However, if I take the link created for video (mp4) and go to Facebook or Twitter, they aren't able to render a thumbnail from it and instead show a very generic googleapi link with no image. Clicking the link will take me to asset just fine, but the representation of it prior looks terrible. However, a link to an image like (png) works just fine.

Using Facebook's sharing debugger, I can see that it's not able to read the appropriate metadata in order to properly handle the video file (again fine with an image). I tried to manually insert `og:` tags in the Firebase metadata for the asset, but those are not picked up at all by Facebook.

Here is an example of a video link to show format (the link won't be active):

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mobile-ios-xxx.com/o/videos%2F-LCFuqpLapuqyFBqXRhl%2Fvideo.mp4?alt=media&token=62913a72-f29a-41b3-9518-a4d1f21107d8
```

Here is an example of an image link which works just fine and has similar structure to the video above (the link won't be active):

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mobile-ios-xxx.com/o/Image%2F-LCFuqpLapuqyFBqXRhl%2Fthumbnail.png?alt=media&token=4833467h-edac-4c23-a084-4e00ceb503r2
```

I have reached out to Firebase support who point the finger at Facebook/Twitter, so no help there. I also created a bit.ly link of the above as a test, but the results were the same.

Any suggestions for how I can get a link that can be properly read by Facebook/Twitter?

Comment: Given that you are sharing the download URL, Cloud Storage for Firebase just serves the raw content that you stored. It doesn't serve any of the metadata that (apparently) Facebook and Twitter need to show a thumbnail for the video. The solution is to figure out what they need, and serve that from a different source or a separate request.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Why does storage allow for the entry of metadata including custom metadata, if it cannot be used or can it only be used in a different context?

Comment: It can be used by other Firebase clients. As far as I know this metadata is now exposed through the download URL.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it does not appear to be used by Facebook unfortunately when using the download url. To be fair I just tested with Amazon S3 and the issue is the same. If Facebook allowed one to post a URL and a separate image, I could get around this issue, but they don't allow both.

Comment: I don't know enough about the Facebook API to help with that. All I can say is what Firebase Storage does in this case. A reframing of the question to "how to provide my own thumbnail when posting a link to facebook" might give better results.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Thanks for the help. I guess that is where I go next. Was hoping to solve it with the link itself. Appreciate it.

Comment: @C6Silver Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @TroyDCThompson - Not through cloud storage hosting. We wound up going in a different direction for the project that this was apart of.

Comment: @C6Silver Which direction to do you recommend? I'm stuck